# Intermittent authentication error when posting to a pubsub topic

Tags: google-oauth, google-cloud-pubsub

We have a data pipeline built in Google Cloud Dataflow that consumes messages from a pubsub topic and streams them into BigQuery. In order to test that it works successfully we have some tests that run in a CI pipeline, these tests post messages onto the pubsub topic and verify that the messages are written to BigQuery successfully.

This is the code that posts to the pubsub topic:

```py
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
def post_messages(project_id, topic_id, rows)
    futures = dict()
    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(
        project_id, topic_id
    )

    def get_callback(f, data):
        def callback(f):
            try:
                futures.pop(data)
            except:
                print("Please handle {} for {}.".format(f.exception(), data))

        return callback

    for row in rows:
        # When you publish a message, the client returns a future. Data must be a bytestring
        # ...
        # construct a message in var json_data
        # ...
        message = json.dumps(json_data).encode("utf-8")
        future = publisher.publish(
            topic_path,
            message
        )
        futures_key = str(message)
        futures[futures_key] = future
        future.add_done_callback(get_callback(future, futures_key))
    # Wait for all the publish futures to resolve before exiting.
    while futures:
        time.sleep(1)
```

When we run this test in our CI pipeline it has started failing intermittently with error

```
21:38:55: AuthMetadataPluginCallback "<google.auth.transport.grpc.AuthMetadataPlugin object at 0x7f5247407220>" raised exception!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/envs/py3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_plugin_wrapping.py", line 89, in __call__
    self._metadata_plugin(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/py3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 101, in __call__
    callback(self._get_authorization_headers(context), None)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/py3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 87, in _get_authorization_headers
    self._credentials.before_request(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/py3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 134, in before_request
    self.apply(headers)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/py3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 110, in apply
    _helpers.from_bytes(token or self.token)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/py3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/_helpers.py", line 130, in from_bytes
    raise ValueError("***0!r*** could not be converted to unicode".format(value))
ValueError: None could not be converted to unicode
Error: The operation was canceled.
```

Unfortunately this only fails in our CI pipeline, and even then it is failing intermittently (only fails on a small percentage of all CI pipeline runs). If I run the same test locally it succeeds every time. When running in the CI pipeline the code is authenticating as a service account whereas when I run it locally it is authenticating as myself

I know from the error message that it is failing on this code:

```py
if isinstance(result, six.text_type):
        return result
    else:
        raise ValueError("{0!r} could not be converted to unicode".format(value))
```

https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/3c3fbf40b07e090f2be7fac5b304dbf438b5cd6c/google/auth/_helpers.py#L127-L130

which is in a python library from google that we install using pip.

Clearly the expression:

```py
isinstance(result, six.text_type)
```

is evaluating to `False`. I put a breakpoint on that code when I ran it locally and discovered that under normal circumstances (i.e. when it works) the value of `result` is something like this:

[image: screenshot of debugger displaying value of variable result]

That looks like some sort of auth token.

Given the error message:

> ValueError: None could not be converted to unicode

it seems that whatever action is being undertaken by the google authentication libraries it is passing `None` through to the code shown above.

I am at the bounds of my knowledge here. Given this is only failing in a CI pipeline I don't have the opportunity to put a breakpoint in my code and debug it. Given the call stack in the error message this is something to do with authentication.

I'm hoping someone can advise on a course of action.

Can anyone explain a means by which I can discover why `None` is being passed through to the code that is raising an error?

Comment: Do you have special default encoding on your CI?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: If the texts that you are encoding into json are in [unicode](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#unicode). you can try `ensure_ascii=False`. At your code it would look like: `message = json.dumps(json_data, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf-8")`.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  @syrkuit's suggestion to filter logs (see: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/issues/927#issuecomment-1013902988) does help with messy output. Hopefully there will be a fix soon.

Comment: We haven’t witnessed this happening for many weeks now. I suspect (but cannot confirm) that this has been solved by us updating the dependencies (i.e. the Google cloud python libraries). Fingers crossed it’s fixed permanently.

Comment: This may or may not be useful. At the time I started this thread we were using google-api-core=2.2.2, google-auth=2.3.3, google-auth-httplib2=0.1.0, google-auth-oauthlib=0.4.6. The only one of those that’s changed if I look at our list of deps today is google-api-core=2.3.2.

Comment: I tried everything and still I get the same error. @jamiet your issue was completely resolved?

Comment: It has not reoccurred since my message on 18th January.

Comment: What is your grpcio package on? Should be this: `grpcio>=1.47.0`

Comment: btw, I create an issue in GitHub : https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/737#issuecomment-1193553616

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had the same error. Finally solved it by using a JSON Web Token for authentication per Google's [Quckstart](https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/index.html). Like so:

```
import json
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from google.auth import jwt

def post_messages(credentials_path, topic, list_of_messages):

    credentials_dict = json.load(open(credentials_path,'r'))

    audience = "https://pubsub.googleapis.com/google.pubsub.v1.Publisher"
    credentials_ob = jwt.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
        credentials_dict, audience=audience
    )

    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(credentials=credentials_ob)

    for message_dict in list_of_message_dicts:
    
        message = json.dumps(message_dict, default=str).encode("utf-8")
    
        future = publisher.publish(topic, message)
```

We also updated our environment but it didn't fix the `ValueError` until we changed to `jwt`. Here's the environment in any case:

```
google-api-core==2.4.0
google-api-python-client==2.36.0
google-auth==2.3.2
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
google-cloud-core==2.1.0
google-cloud-pubsub==2.9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried the jwt solution above and though it solved the issue, it drastically degraded my write throughput.

Offering another work around that solved this issue for me.
My GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var was set to the location of my key-file. Instead, unset that env variable and, at the start of your process, run

`gcloud auth activate-service-account {account_name} --key-file {location_of_key_file}`

This allows the google auth to bypass a key file and use the default service account set up (which is now the original, intended service account).  Works with normal throughput and zero errors. :)